# How to replace an image on QML (Qt) file by an other image do not have in Resource

Tags: c++, image, qt, qml

I have a Qml file, designed an image on a button in it.

**Menu.qml**

```
(...)
ToolButton {
  Image {
    (...)
    Image {
      id: img1
      source: "qrc:/Images/img_1.png" 
    }
  }  
}
```

Now I want, if I have a picture in folder C:/Images/, eg **C:/Pic/img_2.png**, after load success **Menu.qml**, it's automatically replace img_1.png (in resource) by img_2.png (not in resource).

Can somebody help me please? 
(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 2):

`Image` allows users to change image source at runtime using JavaScript code. So whenever you want to change the image you can assign a new source URL to the `img1.source`.

```
image.source = 'file:/c:/Pic/img_2.png';
```

Note that for local files you should use `file:` protocol scheme.

Comment: Did you test that out? I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure it requires three forward slashes: `file:///C:/Pic/img_2.png`

Comment: Thanks a lot for `file:/`
I try one forward slashe and it's still work..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you can change properties after loading the button by attaching to signal [`Component.onCompleted`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html)

```
(...)
ToolButton {
  Image {
    (...)
    Image {
      id: img1
      source: "qrc:/Images/img_1.png" 
      Component.onCompleted: {
        source = "file://C:/Pic/img_2.png"
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My qml file has many Images, and each image **could be replace** (if exist a picture in folder C by the `id`), **or not** (if not exist). And my teacher wanted to approval once time. So I have choose this way: write the function browse that folder and listed all the appropriate file name, and replace

        `var pngName = arrayIcon[i];
        var controlName = pngName.slice(0,-4);
        eval(controlName).source = pathPng + pngName;`

Then after load success, call this function. Currently, it still works well.

Answer (score 0):

[Managing Resource Files with the Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html)

> ...all files specified by relative paths in QML will be loaded from the resource system instead. Use of the resource system is completely transparent to the QML layer; this means all QML code should refer to resource files using relative paths and should not use the qrc scheme. This scheme should only be used from C++ code for referring to resource files.

So all you need to do to load an image outside resource file is to use an its absolute path.